# Angular 4 implementation for google.maps.places.AutocompleteService

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I want to implement functionality of keyword search with google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(). HOwever, not able to get any documentation or guidelines for it. PLease share examples/documentation if anyone has already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete#installation for implementation. With some changes and customization I was able to implement as per customer requirements.